# Create new user works with ruby 1.9.2 but fails with ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Rails 3.2.8 and Devise 2.1.2 (latest) and am baffled as to why I can create a user just fine with Ruby 1.9.2 but not with Ruby 1.9.3, using *exactly* the same codebase.

Rails console:

```
User.find_or_create_by_email('example@example.com', :password => 'example', :first_name => 'Super', :last_name => 'Admin', :terms_and_conditions => true)
```

The output in 1.9.3 shows ROLLBACK (see below), but I just can't seem to figure out why.

Output (partial) when using 1.9.2:

```
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("created_at", "event", "item_id", "item_type", "object", "whodunnit") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 10 Oct 2012 13:57:07 UTC +00:00], ["event", "create"], ["item_id", 20], ["item_type", "OrderType"], ["object", nil], ["whodunnit", nil]]
  Currency Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "currencies".* FROM "currencies" WHERE "currencies"."code" = 'USD' LIMIT 1
SQL (2.4ms)  INSERT INTO .. 
(continues with the next insert statement)
```

Output (partial) when using 1.9.3:

```
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("created_at", "event", "item_id", "item_type", "object", "whodunnit") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 10 Oct 2012 12:29:49 UTC +00:00], ["event", "create"], ["item_id", 16], ["item_type", "OrderType"], ["object", nil], ["whodunnit", nil]]
  Currency Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "currencies".* FROM "currencies" WHERE "currencies"."code" = 'USD' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<User id: 4, first_name: "Super", last_name: "Admin", admin_notes: nil, email: "example@example.com", ... 
(stops)
```

I am thinking this could be an issue with Devise but am not sure.

Would appreciate any help!

---

Update Oct 19:

I found out that the cause of the problem is an `after_create` callback in user.rb that creates a "broker" (through the broker model) where it sets commission = 9.95

From the annotation in broker.rb:

```
#  commission :decimal(, )
```

And more from broker.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
PRICE_REGEX = /^([1-9]\d{0,20}|0)(\.\d{0,3})?$/
PRICE_ERROR_MESSAGE = "Must be a number. If you want to include decimals, please use comma as decimal separator. Periods (.) = thousand separator cannot be used."
validates :commission, :format => {:with => PRICE_REGEX, :message => PRICE_ERROR_MESSAGE }, :allow_blank => true
```

As written above, setting broker commission to 9.95 works fine with ruby 1.9.2 but fails with ruby 1.9.3.

When saving it through rails console in 1.9.3, I get an "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed..." error. No error in 1.9.2.

If I set it to 10 instead of 9.95 it works in both 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 (broker commission is set to 10).

If I set it to 9,95 (comma, not period) the user and broker is created fine but the broker commission is set to 0.

As the validation error message says, periods (.) are not allowed so it makes sense that the validation fails, but then it would have been a bug in ruby 1.9.2 that had it work before I switched to 1.9.3.

Any good explanation would be welcome :-)

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a validation issue? The `INSERT` looks nearly the same.

Comment: @tadman Thanks - but the code is run on the same codebase, so how could it be a validation issue?

Comment: It could be that one of your `before_save` type routines is inadvertently returning `false` and halting the save operation, or there's something like a uniqueness check that's failing. Be sure you're using `save!` or `create!` to properly trigger exceptions.

Comment: I tried the following in rails console:  
`createuser =User.find_or_create_by_email('example@example.com', :password => 'example', :first_name => 'Super', :last_name => 'Admin', :terms_and_conditions => true)`
`createuser.save!`  

But get no errors/exceptions (the ROLLBACK appears already in step 1, i.e. before createuser.save!). 

Is that how you would do it? (I am a newbie to rails, so please bare with me)Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: Hi all. I've found out what causes the problem. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

After failed save check @user.errors it may have a clue

EDIT

In your Rails console

```
@user = User.find_or_create_by_email('example@example.com', :password => 'example', :first_name => 'Super', :last_name => 'Admin', :terms_and_conditions => true)
@user.errors
```

or

```
@user.errors.full_messages
```

Comment: Can it be done without messing with the model? If yes, how can I do that in console? (newbie to Rails, so hope you will bare with me)

Comment: `createuser.errors.full_messages` gives you nice, readable output if there's any errors.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Tried it but no error messages are shown :-/ When I run `@user = User.find_or_create_by_email(...` (still get the ROLLBACK output) and then run `@user.errors.full_messages`in console, I just get `=> []`  Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that this user exists?